# How to add a subtitle below a large title in a navigation view in swift ui?

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationview

How can I add a subtitle under a large title that was defined this way?

```
NavigationView{

        VStack(){
           //"Some code" 
        }
        .navigationTitle("Analytics")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to what I was looking for: basically create the top of the screen as it would normally be without a navigationView and then add a scrollview underneath.

```
HStack {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
        Text("Title")
             .font(.largeTitle)
             .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
             .fontWeight(.bold)
                        
        Text("subtitle")
             .font(.subheadline)
             .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
     }
                
     Spacer()         
 }
 .padding()
            
            
            
 ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
 NavigationView{
            VStack(){
                //"Some code"
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Title").font(.largeTitle).bold()
                        Text("Subtitle").font(.subheadline)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How would you make this VStack behave like a navigationTitle? because when scrolling down the NavigationBar is too small. Also it is compressed on top left corner, I'm trying to add some spacing.

Answer (score 2):

Seems "navigationSubtitle" is only for macos, this is another way to do it in ios:

```
        .navigationBarItems(leading: VStack {
            Text("Analytics").font(.largeTitle).bold()
            Text("Subtitle")
        })
```

Edit update:

you could also try this, with some loss of font choice:

```
.navigationTitle("Subtitle") 
.navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Analytics").font(.largeTitle).bold())
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but there's a small problem: The title and subtitle are not in the same position as navigationTitle was. So there's a blank space at the NavigationTitle's spot and the items are compacted to the top left corner. So when scrolling down the NavigationBar is too small to fit the items. Maybe making the bar bigger and add some padding would be a work around

Comment: you could try this instead, with some loss of font choice:   " .navigationTitle("Subtitle")  
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Analytics").font(.largeTitle).bold())"